# JQuery - add click event to LI or SPAN elements?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, events

I am trying to add a click event to a LI element but it is not firing in the page.  My page markup looks like:

```
<div id="Navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="navPrevNext inactive">|&lt; First Page</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext inactive">&lt; Prev Page</li>
    <li class="navIndex selected" title="0 ">1</li>
    <li class="navIndex notselected" title="1 ">2</li>
    <li class="navIndex notselected" title="2 ">3</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext active" title="1">Next Page &gt;</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext active" title="2">Last Page &gt;|</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And in my JS code I have:

```
$("#Navigation li").live('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault; this.blur(); return updateNavigation($(this).attr('title')); });
```

Any thoughts?

TIA

Comment: one thing: e.preventDefault should be e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You sure you have jquery 1.3 included in your code?  The following works fine (direct copy and paste from your question) for me when I click on any of the LIs:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateNavigation(title) {
    alert(title);
}

$("#Navigation li").live('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault; 
    this.blur(); 
    return updateNavigation($(this).attr('title')); 
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Navigation">
<ul>
    <li class="navPrevNext inactive">|&lt; First Page</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext inactive">&lt; Prev Page</li>
    <li class="navIndex selected" title="0 ">1</li>
    <li class="navIndex notselected" title="1 ">2</li>
    <li class="navIndex notselected" title="2 ">3</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext active" title="1">Next Page &gt;</li>
    <li class="navPrevNext active" title="2">Last Page &gt;|</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Are you sure your updateNavigation function is working right?  Maybe it's being triggered but something is wrong within it...

Comment: My dev environment was conspiring against me.  After a reboot my JS file was updated and it worked as expected.  Seems the older file was being held in the temp cache.  <grrr/>

Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing as @Parrots and it works for me.  You might, however, want to change your selector to:

```
$("#Navigation li[title]" ).live('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault;
     this.blur();
     return updateNavigation($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

So that the handler is only applied to elements that have a title attribute.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that out!  (Better to avoid errors than handle them later)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was using a popup list that the user selected.  Basically the user clicks an input box and a ul is revealed.

This worked great with a 500ms animation, but when switching to 250ms the scrolling down animation was too fast and apparently the click event never fired on a li.

Answer (score 0):

don´t use span it´s better delegate