# li Click Event Not Firing

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="tags">
<li class="tab1 tabactive">New Arrivals</li>
<li class="tab2" id="hot-home">Best Deals</li>
<li style="border-right: 0;" class="tab3">Today's Sale</li>
</ul>
```

I added the following with Firebug:

```
jQuery('#tags li').click(function(){
alert("Hello dreamdu!");
 });
```

When I click the LI the alert is not showing, can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/6qGjL/

Comment: it's too werid,but in my site, it can't work.when i change it to mouseover.

Comment: working fine for me http://jsbin.com/otidem/2/watch

Comment: some jquery conflict issue may be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on your site, it appears that the div with the ID `tagContent` is layered on top of your `tags` element.  Your code is fine, you just need to fix your CSS so that the elements you want can actually be clicked on.

Comment: @NaveedButt I don't think it can, but what I meant was that there is an element positioned on top of the element with the click event.  So when you click, you are actually clicking on the top element instead of the one below it that has the click event.  [I made an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ak913vv9/), but in general you can fix the layering issues with `z-index` or playing with the `position` of various elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Refer
```

[bind event to li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835993/jquery-add-click-event-to-li-or-span-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working for me . i tried it into your page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#con > ul li").click(function(){
 alert("working");
});
});
```